# Sybase Sequence

Tags: sequence, sap-ase

I am creating a sequence in sybase but getting mentioned exception, can anyone please help?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SEQUENCE dbo.event_id_sequence
    START WITH 100
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 100
    NO MAXVALUE
    NO CACHE  
    NO CYCLE    
go

GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE dbo.event_id_sequence TO userID maintenance
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE dbo.event_id_sequence TO userID readonly
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE dbo.event_id_sequence TO userID reports
go
```

Exception:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-14 -------------------------
>    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'REPLACE'.
>    Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 2
>    [Executed: 7/7/14 2:06:02 PM EDT ] [Execution: 0/ms]
>
> [Error] Script lines: 15-19 ------------------------
>    Incorrect syntax near 'USAGE'.
>    Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 84
>
> [Error] Script lines: 15-19 ------------------------
>    Incorrect syntax near 'USAGE'.
>    Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 84
>
> [Error] Script lines: 15-19 ------------------------
>    Incorrect syntax near 'USAGE'.
>    Msg: 102, Level: 15, State: 84

[Executed: 7/7/14 2:06:02 PM EDT ] [Execution: 0/ms]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sybase ASE does not have `sequence`, the code you found is likely pulled from Sybase IQ or possible SQL Anywhere.

Instead of using `sequence`, you should look at using [`IDENTITY` columns](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X37315.htm) instead.

If that does not suit your needs, [Sybase suggests](http://web.archive.org/web/20140615004406/http://m.sybase.com/detail?id=860) a number of other approaches that may give you what you are looking for.

> **Methods:**
>
> Methods which can be used to produce a monotonic series are:
>
> Max Plus One
>
> Enhanced Max Plus One
>
> Next Key Table
>
> Identity Property

All of these are detailed in the linked document.

I would also suggest reviewing page 20 of this presentation on [Migration from Oracle to ASE](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/f0a67a75-893c-3010-d3a0-f7e19f59ced7?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&57909044114253) from SAP Techwave.  There is some sample code on how to emulate SEQUENCE using a sequence table/procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE my_seq (seq int) 
go 
//initialize the sequence 
INSERT INTO my_seq select 0 
go 
CREATE PROCEDURE get_seq (@seq int OUTPUT) 
AS UPDATE my_seq SET seq = seq+1 
SELECT @seq = seq FROM my_seq 
go 
// execute the sp to get the next sequence number 
DECLARE @seq int 
EXEC get_seq @seq OUTPUT 
INSERT INTO m_table VALUES (@seq,..) 
go
```

Outdated Link - http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=860